# how to convert normal telegram file to a downloadable link

Tags: telegram

How to convert my normal telegram file to a link so I can download it, without redirecting to telegram, from my website.
I have one another question?

I mean I wanted to add a download feature In my website, so for that what should i use, and I just want that the user click on the link and it starts downloading.

Comment: Telegram operates via ["MTProto" protocol](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto) - not HTTP/s. so unless you create a bridge server yourself, I doubt you will have any luck there.

Comment: so can you suggest any other, platform which I can use.